# Change color of a cell of a datagridview inside a tabpanel

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tabs

I got a tabControl with two tabPanels inside. The tabPanels contains a datagridview and i'm trying to change the color of the cell.
If i change the color of the first datagrid contained in the first tabPanel it works. But if i do the same with the other tabPanel the code didn't do nothing.

```
 dgvInTheFirstTabPanel.Rows[0].Cells[6].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

This work fine, but...

```
dgvInTheSecondTabPanel.Rows[0].Cells[6].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

This didn't work, i think that the problem is the change of the tab panel active.

Comment: whats the error that you get?

Comment: i didn't get an error just the code didn't do nothing

Comment: Is the datagridview control added to the second tab at the time when you change its color?

Comment: Yes, and the data is charged but the color of the cell didn't change

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem, exist a bug that don't recognize the tabs if you didn't click inside one of them. For solve this you can do this in the load of the form. In this way you can modify the objects that are contain in the others tab.

```
private void main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //Scan all tabs
                tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[1];
                tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[2];
                tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[0];
    ...
    }
     Best regards
```

Then you can modify the color of the cell or another property of your dataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

```
tabControl1.SelectedTab = 0 
dgvInTheFirstTabPanel.Rows[0].Cells[6].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

tabControl1.SelectedTab = 1
dgvInTheSecondTabPanel.Rows[0].Cells[6].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```